# How to stop LINQ to SQL stored procedure wiring code from being automatically generated?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a the LINQ to SQL wiring code for a stored procedure that returns `IMultipleResult` implemented in a partial class.

When you add new objects in the `dbml` file, stored procedure wiring code is generated again; This causes the code be in both my partial class and `designer.cs`.

How can I mark a stored procedure so that the wiring code would not be automatically generated by making changes in the `dbml` designer?

```
namespace Audit
{
    public partial class LinqAuditDataContext 
    {
        [Function(Name = "getRows")]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresE))]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresWater))]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresV))]
        public IMultipleResults getRows([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> page, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> rowsshow, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "NVarChar(30)")] string table, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Bit")] System.Nullable<bool> fact, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> id_obj)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), page, rowsshow, table, fact, id_obj);
            return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted getrows in dbml file and defined in a different file in a partial class.
It works ...
Maybe there's an idea?

function in partial  LinqAuditDataContext

```
public partial class LinqAuditDataContext 
    {
        [Function(Name = "getRows")]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresE))]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresWater))]
        [ResultType(typeof(featuresV))]
        public   IMultipleResults getRows(System.Nullable<int> page,  System.Nullable<int> rowsshow, 
            string table, System.Nullable<bool> fact, 
            System.Nullable<int> id_obj, bool t)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), page, rowsshow, table, fact, id_obj);
            return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
        }


    }
```